# Conan require build in different runtime

Tags: visual-studio, conan

I'm beginners in Conan.
I would like to add a requirement to my projet and link this requirement in static.
But I have a runtime issue, my project need to be build on '/MD' but Conan still compile my requirement on '/MT'.

In my case I would like boost on static but in 'MD' runtime.

```
from conans import ConanFile
class MyProject(ConanFile):
    requires = "zlib/1.2.13", "boost/1.80.0", "cpprestsdk/2.10.18", "opencv/4.5.5", "geogram/1.8.2@lib/dynamic"
    generators = "visual_studio"
    default_options = {"cpprestsdk:shared": True, "opencv:shared": True, "geogram:shared": True}
    
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"   
            
    def configure(self):
        self.settings.compiler.version = "17"
```

Comment: What passed is based on your [Conan profile](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/profiles.html), you need to update it to use `compiler.runtime=MD`.

Comment: This is already the case, `compiler.runtime` is already equal at `MD`

Comment: Settings cannot be defined in recipes, they can only come from profiles or command line. Defining their values in recipes can be ignored, or eventually raise an error.

Comment: It can happen that the dependency build systems is somehow hardcoding /MT. I'd recommend to submit a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan. Also to use a simple dependency, generated with ``conan new hello/0.1 -m=cmake_lib``, to rule-out that it is a recipe issue of a particular dependency or a Conan tool issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution related to my problem which, I guess, should work only with Boost require.

```
def package_info(self):
    self.cpp_info.cxxflags = "-runtime-link=shared" #will compile on "/MD" runtime
```

I explore a bit the cmake of Boost and I found some condition related to the runtime.